# Http request is aborted when it is being sent from ServiceBase.OnShutdown, but not in OnStop

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, https, dotnet-httpclient

I have a windows service that will send out an https request in `OnShutdown` and `OnStop`, and when I simply restart the service from task manager it works just fine. However the same code will throw this exception when the service is stopped from a server shutdown instead:

`System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter1.GetResult()`

Also, the request is happening inside of a larger `Task`.

I'm not sure how stopping the service from Task Manager or Services vs. shutting down Windows would make the same logic behave differently. What could cause this issue, or how can I troubleshoot?

Comment: Maybe Windows shutdown is closing the network before the service.

Comment: yeah i was actually thinking that too, but how would I confirm?

Comment: Try to enumerate all the `NetworkInterfaces` and check their `OperationalStatus`

Comment: The Ethernet one, which is the one being used for internet is up right before the request gets sent. The loopback is as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out for sure if being inside a `Task.Run()` was the problem, or what else might have been causing this request to be aborted. However, I was able to keep it from getting aborted by using the `SystemEvents.SessionEnded` event:

```
public void Start()
{
    SystemEvents.SessionEnded += OnSessionEnded;

...

public void Stop()
{
    SystemEvents.SessionEnded -= OnSessionEnded;

...

private void OnSessionEnded(object sender, SessionEndedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (eventArgs.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
    {
        SendRequest();
    }
}
```

This is a simplified version of what my code is doing. Sending out this http request when the `SessionEnded` fired, rather than waiting for the `ServiceBase.OnStop` to be called, allows the request to complete successfully. And the change doesn't affect the way the service normally shuts down. The main difference I can see is that it's happening earlier in the service shutdown process now.